# fork() + pipe() + python + Mandelbrot Set

Tags: python-3.x, unix, parallel-processing, fork, ipc

```
import os

from PIL import Image

def escape_time_algorithm(c, m):
    z = complex(0, 0)
    for i in range(m):
        z = z ** 2 + c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return i
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    encoding = 'utf-8'

    width, height = 1280, 720
    x1 = -2.0
    x2 = 2.0
    y1 = -2.0
    y2 = 2.0

    max_iter = 100

    fork_number = 2

    pipe_list = []

    for fork_number in range(fork_number):
        pipe_list.append(list(os.pipe()))

    shutdown_list = []
    p_id = 0

    for process_number in range(fork_number):
        p_id = os.fork()
        if p_id < 0:
            print("Child {} failed!".format(process_number))
            exit(-1)
        elif p_id == 0:
            os.close(pipe_list[process_number][0])
            print("Child {} created {}!".format(process_number, os.getpid()))

            information = str()
            for x in range(process_number * (width // fork_number), (process_number + 1) * (width // fork_number)):
                zx = x * (x2 - x1) / width + x1
                for y in range(height):
                    zy = y * (y2 - y1) / height + y1
                    color = escape_time_algorithm(complex(zx, zy), max_iter)
                    information += str(x) + str(y) + str(color) + " "

            if os.write(pipe_list[process_number][1], bytes(information, encoding='utf-8')) < 0:
                print("Writing color failed!")
                exit(-1)

            os.close(pipe_list[process_number][1])
            exit(0)

        else:
            shutdown_list.append(p_id)

    if p_id > 0:
        image = Image.new("RGB", size=(width, height))

        for process_number in range(fork_number):
            os.close(pipe_list[process_number][1])

            x_bound = (process_number + 1) * (width // fork_number) - (process_number * (width // fork_number))

            information = os.read(pipe_list[process_number][0], x_bound)

            os.close(pipe_list[process_number][0])

            for splitted_information in information[:-1].decode().split(" "):
                image.putpixel((int(splitted_information[0]), int(splitted_information[1])), (int(splitted_information[2]) % 4 * 64, int(splitted_information[2]) % 8 * 32, int(splitted_information[2]) % 16 * 16))


        for i_pid in shutdown_list:
            print("Waiting for PID: {} to finish.".format(i_pid))
            os.waitpid(i_pid, 0)
            print("PID: {} has shut down.".format(i_pid))

        image.save("result_fork.png")
```

I want to draw different parts of the screen as input to the child processes I fork(). This code draws something but it's all stacked on the top left. I think there is a problem with the pipe structure, but I can't think of any other approach to this pipe implementation. Maybe I haven't been able to solve the problem of each child process having its own image object. Where is the error and what approach would you recommend ?

Edit:Actually, there is one more thing I haven't mentioned. When I run the program I get the following output

```
Child 0 created 22140!
Waiting for PID: 22140 to finish.
PID: 22140 has shut down.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is it printing a one child even though I selected the fork number 2?

Edit 2: With the help of @hobbs i changed information to this

```
information += str(x) + " " + str(y) + " " + str(color) + "\t"
```

so parsing mechanism evolved to something like this

```
for splitted_information in information[:-1].decode().split("\t"):
    image.putpixel((int(splitted_information.split(" ")[0]), 
                   int(splitted_information.split(" ")[1])), 
                   (int(splitted_information.split(" ")[2]) % 4 * 64, 
                   int(splitted_information.split(" ")[2]) % 8 * 32, 
                   int(splitted_information.split(" ")[2]) % 16 * 16))
```

But i found more serious problem. I was getting the os.read() buffer `(x_bound * height)` but this is not correct because does not one value come from the height, more than one value comes. (x, y, space char, tab char etc.) So buffer should be at least `(x_bound * height * <some integer>)` But I can't predict the exact number. And i finally saw some result however I couldn't fully solve the problems I wrote above. I can't create a high resolution mandelbrot image because I can't fully solve the above problems. (For now max res is 200 x 200)

[image: 80x80]

Edit 3 : I am programming this code on Ubuntu 22.04 WSL on Windows 11 x64. RAM is 16 GB but WSL allocated 8 GB of RAM. Python can only read up to 2^16 bytes from os.read(). If I choose a higher buffer, it gives a memory error. So I can't create higher resolution images because they don't fit in the 2^16 buffer. If I switch to native linux, will this limit disappear ?

Comment: `information += str(x) + str(y) + str(color) + " "` seems like a simple mistake... a space at the end, but no spaces between the values?

Comment: each information has x, y, color and space at then end. So final string be like "x1y1color1 x1y2color2 x1y3color3 ). When i parse this extract final space and split using " ". I think I parse it by following this rule in the parent process.

Comment: you're not, because that format is impossible to parse.

Comment: Now I understand. If x and y are 2 or more digits, my method will not work.

Comment: I would suggest space between fields and newline between records, and to use readline on the consumer end. I would also suggest organizing the code so that you can test parts of it in isolation, to make problems easier to find.